# extjs gridfilters private methods

Tags: extjs

In gridfilters.js, why are some methods marked as `/** private **/`
When I override these methods, it seems that the overridden method is not called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override private methods but you shouldn't override private methods. The only thing /** private **/ does is make it so the method does not appear in the ExtJS Api documentation. You shouldn't override these methods because they are subject to change and are for internal use only.